# database design question with Partition and Replication

Tags: mysql, database-design, replication, partitioning

I have a main database that runs on a server with good resources and, let's say, a dozen satellites that replicate data. Satellites have less resources than main server.

In that database there is a BIG table, that I want partitioned in ranges because in fact each satellite cares about his own specific range.

```
PARTITION BY RANGE( ID ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2000000),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3000000),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (4000000),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ...
);
```

Let's say satellite 1 cares about table IDs that start with 1, satellite 2 cares about IDs that start with 2 and so on. (all IDs are numbered in millions).

Is it possible to replicate on each satellite only data that are relevant to the satellite? I mean I don't want p2 and p3 on satellite 1, only p1 is relevant for satellite 1. But I don't know how to say to the replication engine that I want only such a part of the data.

Is it only possible to replicate only one partition of the partition scheme?

Comment: Not possible.  Replication filtering is only on database and/or table.  See binlog/replicate_do/ignore_...

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are looking for NoSQL DB with Data shard across nodes. Check the [MySQL NDB Cluster](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html).